# How does ng-bind and ng-bind-html prevent XSS?

Tags: angularjs, xss, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I have been trying to study XSS on Angular JS and found that ng-bind and ng-bind-html prevents XSS against arbitrary user input which has already been encoded by html-encode in server site. How exactly does this work ? Is there any way to by pass this so that XSS could be executed ?

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bind-html` usages [$sce.getTrustedHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#getTrusted) to sanitise the passed html.